# how to parse existing XML document with a specific tag server with a REST API

Tags: java, xml, rest, api, parsing

I am new to writing web servers and I am wanting to ***learn more*** / ***need help***

**I was wondering how I would go about in trying to read information such as the description tag from an existing XML document containing the following data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data>
   <smartphones>
     <smartphone>
       <name>Samsung</name>
       <description>This is an Android Device</description>
     </smartphone>
   </smartphones>
   <smartphones>
     <smartphone>
       <name>Apple</name>
       <description>This is an Apple Device</description>
     </smartphone>
   </smartphones>
 </data>
```

**into a JAVA web server which follows REST API, where the correct description of the smartphone name should be displayed. E.g if I call the smartphone name (apple) then the description of the phone name should be displayed correctly.**

> *(assume there are more smartphones) *
>   *(would I use multiple hosts with different @Path for each smartphone? :s)*

would anyone know a good way to learn how to do this, as i have been googling for a few days and trying to learn different methods online however none of which can provide me with details on how to pull information from an existing document.

Some examples on how to do this with some explanations if possible, or links would be much appreciated as I want to learn and understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jaxb library to read this XML and parse into your Java beans.
You can capture the smartphones into a List.

For your reference: [Vogella Jaxb tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html)

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial this helps! Just another questions would be how would I apply this to a REST web server.

For example if I capture the data, how will I return the values of the XML into a web server with the smartphone name being the parameter and the notes being printed according to the parameter?